# Creating Hash with keys only

Tags: perl, hash

Can only keys be pushed in PERL hash, I mean, Can hash be created without corresponding values?

I want to create a hash which behave just like array i.e. hash with only keys but not corresponding values. Example is given below:

```
my %feedHash;
while(<CFG>)
{
    chomp($_);
    my @val=split(/:/,$_);
    chomp($val[0]);
    my $feedId=$val[0];
    if(!exists $feedHash{$feedId})
    {
      print "\n$feedId Feed is not present";
      $hash{$feedId} = undef;
      mkdir "LoadReports/$feedId" or die $!;                    
    }
    else
    {
       print '\nFeed is already present';
    }
}
```

It is giving message: "Feed is not present" even for same feed id second time in loop

Comment: Just use `undef` as the values: this will allow the Hash (Map) to emulate a Set quite nicely.

Answer (score 7):

You can make hash with your keys, where values are set to `undef`

```
my %hash;
@hash{qw(key1 key2 key3)} = ();
```

to check/set for particular hash key,

```
if (!exists $hash{key4}) { $hash{key4} = undef }
```

Comment: As i am writing a simple code in which i want to check if key is present in hash. If not, then just add key in hash, that's it.

Comment: @user3732491 `$feedHash{$feedId} = undef;` instead of `$hash{$feedId} = undef;`

Comment: @user3732491 you can accept answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially wanting a `%seen` style hash.

You get no benefit from not actually giving the hash a true boolean value, and actually get additional headaches.  I therefore suggest that you style your code like the following:

```
my %seen_feed;

while (<CFG>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id, @vals) = split ':';

    if (! $seen_feed{$id}++) {
        print "\n$id Feed is not present";
        mkdir "LoadReports/$id" or die $!;
    } else {
       print '\nFeed is already present';
    }
}
```